# Colocar el ultimo elemento de un array al principio

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy practicando un pequeño ejercicio de JavaScript y no he podido resolverlo. Espero me puedan orientar.

Intento colocar el objeto con la posición 5 al principio del arreglo. He intentado crear un nuevo arreglo a partir de otras funciones como lo es `array.pop()`, `array.push()`, `array.splice()`, pero ninguna me ha funcionado. Espero puedan orientarme. De antemano, muchas gracias.

Tengo el siguiente Array de objetos:

```js
const currentProgramations = [
  ([0]: object),
  ([1]: object),
  ([2]: object),
  ([3]: object),
  ([4]: object),
  ([5]: object)
]
```

He intentado algo como esto, pero sé que está mal.

```
newArray = this.currentProgramations.slice(5);
const programations = this.currentProgramations.pop();
newArray.push(programations);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si operas sobre un único array, también puedes valerte del método `pop()` para extraer el elemento del final y de `unshift` para insertar este elemento al inicio, por ejemplo:

```js
const arreglo1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
let nuevoArreglo = arreglo1;
nuevoArreglo.unshift(nuevoArreglo.pop());
console.log(nuevoArreglo);
```

Si necesitas (o no importa si) *afectas* el arreglo original, puedes pasar el último elemento al inicio valiéndote de loa métodos `pop()` y  `.concat()`, por ejemplo, de la siguiente manera:

```js
const arreglo1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
const elemento = arreglo1.pop();
let nuevoArreglo = [elemento].concat(arreglo1);

console.log(nuevoArreglo);
```

Si observas, primero extraigo el último elemento, con el que luego armo un nuevo arreglo al que concateno los elementos restantes en el primero.

Esto se puede resumir aún más evitando el uso de la variable elemento así:

```js
const arreglo1 = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
let nuevoArreglo = [arreglo1.pop()].concat(arreglo1);
console.log(nuevoArreglo);
```

En el primer ejemplo, el `arreglo1` queda exactamente como se declaró, mientras que en los dos últimos se le elimina el último elemento.

He preparado los ejemplos con un arreglo de enteros, que es más fácil de observar el comportamiento, pero te funcionará de la misma forma para cualquier arreglo.

Comment: Vaya tan fácil que era , muchísimas gracias me has ayudado mucho , tenia pensado algo así pero no encontraba la forma , mil gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas hacer es primero obtener el último elemento del arreglo y guardarlo en una variable, para obtener el último elemento del arreglo debes hacerlo hacerlo arreglo[arreglo.length]
Una vez que tengas el último elemento entonces haces uso de la función para eliminar el último elemento de un arreglo así Arreglo.shift(), ahora que ya eliminaste el último objeto y ya lo tenés guardado en tu variable temporal debes agregarlo al inició del arreglo usando la función para hacer esto así, arreglo.unshift(variableconultimoelemento) y listo.

Perdón por explicarlo así pero estoy desde mi teléfono y se me complica hacerte algo bonito jaja, podés ver más info de esto aquí https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

Comment: muchísimas gracias por la recomendación , lo había resuelto con dos filter y uniendo los dos arreglos en uno solo pero siento que no era buena practica,  intentare esta forma para seguir aprendiendo , mil gracias.